# How to fix "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType"

Tags: python

I'm making a school project in which I created a game with a 'Instruction' screen and a 'Title' screen (both are different .py files), but I'm having trouble in alterning between the title screen and the instructions.

I have tried changing the key you need to press to proceed and I have tried importing the Title file to the Instructions file and vice-versa.

I really do expect that this function can take me back to the Title when I press "0".

```
from main import titlescreen
global proceed
proceed = None

while proceed not in ("0"): #Line 76
  proceed = input("Press '0' to go back to the tittle.")
  if proceed == "0":
    os.system('clear')
    titlescreen()

ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 113, in <module>
    titlescreen()
  File "main.py", line 92, in titlescreen
    instructions()
  File "/home/runner/no.py", line 76, in instructions
    while pross not in ("0"):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `proceed = None`, then two lines later you're trying to see if `None` is in a string. It looks like you're trying to make it a tuple of strings. If you give proceed a value that is a string or can be converted to a string, you should bypass the error

```
proceed = "2" 

while proceed not in ("0"):
    print("look! I'm printing!", proceed)

    # this part is just to make it so I don't get 
    #an infinite loop without the rest of your code
    proceed = str(int(proceed) - 1)

# ("look! I'm printing!", '2')
# ("look! I'm printing!", '1')
```

If you're going to have multiple buttons to trigger this function, then just add them as you build them. Otherwise, I would suggest just checking for equality and you will be fine with `proceed = None`

```
proceed = None 

while not proceed == "0":
    print("look! I'm printing!", proceed)
    proceed = "0"

# ("look! I'm printing!", None)
```

Comment: That's not a tuple of strings, but otherwise correct.

Comment: You are right, it needs the comma to officially make it a tuple